# Graphic icons for using with "Appreciate this Post" & "Follow updates on this post"

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, icon

What could be good graphic icons for using with "Appreciate this Post" & "Follow updates on this post" in a social web application?

Thanks a lot for your suggestions.

Comment: Does "appreciate" mean "like" or "thanks"? (as in, thanks so much, I really appreciate it)

Comment: yes.. it means 'like this post'

Answer (score 3):

For 'appreciate/like this post' i should use a thumb hand or a little heart.

For 'follow updates on this post' you should use something with a '+'.